Error al crear el quiz: Error: Quiz validation failed: createdBy: Path `createdB y` is required
estoy tratando de crear una pequeña plataforma de quizes con node.js y mongodb, estoy utilizando  middleware de autenticación, al iniciar sesión se asigna un token de validación, hay diferentes roles para usuarios. Ejemplo: estudiante, docente, admin. Al intentar crear un quiz en la consola presenta error. Error al crear el quiz: Error: Quiz validation failed: createdBy: Path createdB y is required. createdBy no está siendo enviado al modelo del quiz, pero este es un campo obligatorio. Al parecer no se está incluyendo el usuario autenticado (req.user._id) en la creación del quiz. he revisado en código y no sé como solucionar el problema. Agradecería la ayuda.







Las imagenes son inútiles, edita la pregunta y coloca el código y mensajes como texto.
